# How to extract data for any 5 days in a month

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to extract data from any 5 days of a month."Not" the last 5 days or the next 5 days.

I basically have to find those customers who perform any action in "ANY" 5 days of a month.

Would appreciate any help on this.

Comment: This is a very broad specification, would `where yourdate between :startdate and :enddate` where you first calculate begindate and enddate as some random 5 day range in a given month work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a table of actions and a specific month in mind, you can do this relatively easily.  The Oracle syntax looks something like this:

```
select customerId
from actions a
where ActionDateTime >= '2014-01-01' and ActionDateTime < '2014-02-01'
group by customerId
having count(distinct trunc(ActionDateTime)) >= 5;
```

Of course, you will have to adapt this for your environment.